# Need to join 3 tables. Need to order by DateTime field and limit by 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

```
CUSTOMERS

Customer ID | Customer Name
----------------------------
1000        | Jonny Ltd.
1001        | James Ltd.
```

```
TICKETS

Ticket ID | Ticket Customer | Ticket Subject
---------------------------------------------
10         | 1000            | Testing Sub
11         | 1001            | Testing Sub 2 
12         | 1001            | Testing Sub 3
```

```
Notes

Note ID | Note Ticket ID | Note Content   | Note Created
---------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 10             | Testing Note1. | 2019-04-20 13:38:16
2       | 10             | Testing Note2. | 2019-04-20 12:52:36
3       | 11             | Testing Note3. | 2019-04-19 10:21:54
```

I want to show each ticket, ordered by their most recent note.
 
When I run this command it doesn't give me the correct response.

```
SELECT `Ticket ID`,`Customer Name`, `Ticket Subject`, `Note Content`, `Note Created`
FROM TICKETS t, CUSTOMERS c, NOTES n
WHERE t.`Ticket Customer` = c.ID AND n.`Note Ticket ID` = t.`Ticket ID`
ORDER BY n.`Note Created` DESC;
```

I want it to output:

```
Ticket ID  | Company Name | Ticket Subject | Note Content   | Note Created
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
10         | Jonny Ltd.   | Testing Sub    | Testing Note1. | 2019-04-20 13:38:16
11         | James Ltd.   | Testing Sub 2  | Testing Note3. | 2019-04-19 10:21:54
12         | James Ltd.   | Testing Sub 3  | NULL           | NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest note data, you need to figure out the most recent note date for each ticket. You can do that with this query:

```
SELECT `Note Ticket ID`, MAX(`Note Created`) AS `Note Created`
FROM Notes
GROUP BY `Note Ticket ID`
```

You can then use that query as a derived table to select all the data from the latest note, and `JOIN` that to the `Customers` and `Tickets` table:

```
SELECT t.`Ticket ID`, c.`Customer Name`, t.`Ticket Subject`,
       n.`Note Content`, n.`Note Created`
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Tickets t ON t.`Ticket Customer` = c.`Customer ID`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Note Ticket ID`, MAX(`Note Created`) AS `Note Created`
           FROM Notes
           GROUP BY `Note Ticket ID`) nc ON nc.`Note Ticket ID` = t.`Ticket ID`
LEFT JOIN Notes n ON n.`Note Ticket ID` = nc.`Note Ticket ID` AND
                     n.`Note Created` = nc.`Note Created`
ORDER BY n.`Note Created` DESC
```

Output:

```
Ticket ID   Ticket Subject  Customer Name   Note Content    Note Created
10          Testing Sub     Jonny Ltd.      Testing Note1.  2019-04-20 13:38:16
11          Testing Sub 2   James Ltd.      Testing Note3.  2019-04-19 10:21:54
12          Testing Sub 3   James Ltd.      null            null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8xkgwpTTRrPLNqiUaUpm1e/0)

Answer (score 2):

You need a subquery to identify the most recent note for each ticket.  This version puts the subquery in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT `Ticket ID`, `Customer Name`, `Ticket Subject`, `Note Content`, `Note Created`
FROM TICKETS t JOIN
     CUSTOMERS c
     ON t.`Ticket Customer` = c.ID LEFT JOIN
     NOTES n
     ON n.`Note Ticket ID` = t.`Ticket ID` AND
        n.`Note Created` = (SELECT MAX(n2.`Note Created`)
                            FROM NOTES n2
                            WHERE n2.`Note Ticket ID` = t.`Ticket ID`
                           )
ORDER BY (n.`Note Created` IS NOT NULL) DESC,
         n.`Note Created` DESC;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use `LEFT JOIN` so you get tickets with no notes.
- I would recommend renaming the columns so they do not include spaces.  Not having to escape identifiers will make it simpler to write queries.
- The `ORDER BY` needs to ensure that the `NULL` values are last.  `DESC` does put the `NULL` values last, but just in case, I added explicit logic for this.

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions instead:

```
SELECT `Ticket ID`, `Customer Name`, `Ticket Subject`, `Note Content`, `Note Created`
FROM TICKETS t JOIN
     CUSTOMERS c
     ON t.`Ticket Customer` = c.ID LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT n.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.`Note Ticket ID` ORDER BY n.`Note Created` DESC) as seqnum
      FROM NOTES n
     ) n
     ON n.`Note Ticket ID` = t.`Ticket ID` AND
        n.seqnum = 1
ORDER BY (n.`Note Created` IS NOT NULL) DESC,
         n.`Note Created` DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use subqueries that get the top row of notes when ordered by time of creation descending or the maximum time of creation respectively.

```
SELECT t.`Ticket ID`,
       c.`Customer Name`,
       t.`Ticket Subject`,
       (SELECT n.`Note Content`
               FROM notes n
               WHERE n.`Note Ticket ID` = t.`Ticket ID`
               ORDER BY n.`Note Created` DESC
               LIMIT 1) `Note Content`,
       (SELECT max(n.`Note Created`)
               FROM notes n
               WHERE n.`Note Ticket ID` = t.`Ticket ID`) `Note Created`
       FROM tickets t,
            LEFT JOIN customers c
                      ON c.`Customer ID` = t.`Ticket Customer`;
```